# accidentally created extra .git folder and now can't access js folder in github

Tags: javascript, git, github, .git-folder

I see the `js` folder in GitHub but unlike my `css` folder the `js` folder icon has 2 folders instead of one like the others. It should only have the `main.js` file in it, not another folder.

Also, I can't access the folder because folder title `js` is not a link and `main.js` is not even listed in the file finder.

Looking through terminal I see that there is a `.git` folder inside the `js` folder. The project folder has a `.git` folder in it as well.

I'm following a tutorial and when the tutorial instructed to stage and push the code to my GitHub repo, I accidentally did that from inside the `js` folder at first, then I did it again from the main project folder. I'm pretty sure this is where something went wrong.

How do I fix this? I'm assuming remove the `.git` folder inside the `js` folder but not sure how to do that and also scared that everything might get deleted.

Thanks in advance! I'm a beginner, please be patient with me :)

Comment: just remove the .git folder and do checkout in <new> empty folder, finally is copy code from <old> folder to <new> one and then check the changes.

Comment: what is the command to remove the .git folder in terminal? and since this is only regarding the .git in js folder only, do i delete from within the js folder? also, not sure what you mean by checkout. lastly, there is nothing actually saved to the .git folder in js so there shouldn't be anything to copy...

Comment: just simply cd to folder and execute `rm -rf .git`  command

Answer (score 0):

Removing the .git folder will work. The command is simple `rm -rf .git`. But if you don't have idea how to use it, better to follow below method. Otherwise there is a chance to remove the other folder unkwnowingly

Use `pwd` command to get the present working directory. Let's say your project folder is : `/home/tina/workspace/myproject`.

If so, use this command - 
`rm -fr /home/tina/workspace/myproject/jsfolderpath/.git` . So that you can make sure the directory you are deleting is correct one.

Note:

- `rm` => command to remove
- `f` => run the command in force
- `r` => run the command recursively